# REPEAT_BYTE(x) macro

Tags: c, linux, macros, linux-kernel, kernel

I was looking the code in `kernel.h` header file in [`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11-.../include/linux/`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L47), I stumbled upon this macro (line 47) :

```
#define REPEAT_BYTE(x)  ((~0ul / 0xff) * (x))
```

After running this example I made:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define REPEAT_BYTE(x) ((~0ul / 0xff) * (x))

int main(void)
{
        long z = 12;    
        fprintf(stderr, "\tz = %ldd (0x%lX)\n"
                        "\tREPEAT_BYTE(%ldd) = %ldd (0x%lX)\n",
                        z, z, z, REPEAT_BYTE(z), REPEAT_BYTE(z));
        return 0;
}
```

I've figured out what it does: It receives an `int` between `0` and `255`(including them), so any one-byte long `int`, and it repeats that byte. This is obvious (except macro's name) when looking at the output:

```
z = 12d (0xC)
REPEAT_BYTE(12d) = 868082074056920076d (0xC0C0C0C0C0C0C0C)
```

However, I still can't understand **how** does this expression work: `((~0ul / 0xff) * (x))`, I could use some help with it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a 64-bit machine, `~0ul` is `0xffffffffffffffff`. Divide that by `0xff` and you get `0x0101010101010101`. Multiply by an 8-bit value and you get that 8-bit value repeated 8 times.

Comment: Math problems are always easy after you've seen the answer :)

Comment: The hex version of `99999999 / 99 * x`